# How do you find out the REAL size of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a `JFrame` which is maximized (`frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`).

I want to find out the size it is now extended to, but `frame.getSize()` returns a size of (0, 0).

Comment: Check after invoking `pack()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frame won't have the maximized size until you make it visible. So your basic code would be:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(frame.getSize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `setExtendedState` I got output in jframe
`java.awt.Dimension[width=408,height=334]`. Please check your code.